# concatenate str and int to call lists via for loops

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, concatenation

I have 3 lists (list_1,list_2...) that have to be called with a for loop.

```
list_1,list_2,list_3 = [],[],[]
number = [1,2,3]

for x,y in enumerate(number):
   z = 'list'+str(x)
   z.append(1)
```

This leads to an error: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'
Any idea to handle the error?

Comment: what are you trying to do with `z.append(1)`?

Comment: Don't use dynamic variables. Instead, put your lists *in a container* and iterate over that

Comment: Your variable z is string type not list. List support append not string

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `z` is a string. You cannot call a variable using its name as a string like that.

You'll prefer considering the following:

```py
list_1, list_2, list_3 = [], [], []
numbers = [1, 2, 3]

for i, number in enumerate(numbers):
    (list_1, list_2, list_3)[i].append(number)
```

This is similar to your original code but I don't recommend such a thing. It's a bit sketchy.
To keep the spirit of your original code while having "good practices", the next code might be better, although your code probably is for learning Python.

```py
lists = [[], [], []] 
numbers = [1, 2, 3]

for i, number in enumerate(numbers):
    lists[i].append(number)
```

```sh
>>> print(lists)
[[1], [2], [3]]
```

**EDIT:** I cannot comment yet since I don't have enough reputation, so here is my answer to your new answer. (you should edit your original post instead of replying to it)

The following code will do the trick:

```py
levels = [[], [], []]
outlines = ['1', '1.1', '1.2', '1.1.1', '1.1.2', '1.1.3']

for i, outline in enumerate(outlines):
   dots_quantity = outline.count('.')
   levels[dots_quantity].append(dots_quantity)
```

```sh
>>> print(levels)
[[0], [1, 1], [2, 2, 2]]
```

To be honest, I don't understand why you would write `dots_quantity` in those lists since the `i-th` list will only contain multiple `i`. You better have multiple counters. Here is what you might like better:

```py
levels = dict()
outlines = ['1', '1.1', '1.2', '1.1.1', '1.1.2', '1.1.3']

for i, outline in enumerate(outlines):
    dots_quantity = outline.count('.')
    if dots_quantity in levels:
        levels[dots_quantity] = levels[dots_quantity] + 1
    else:
        levels[dots_quantity] = 1
```

```sh
>>> print(levels)
{0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3}
```

This `dict` tells you that there is `1` outline with `0` dot, etc...

The advantage of the `dict` way of doing it is that you could have values with as many dots as you'd like and it would still take them into account, whereas with your lists, it couldn't count more than the number of lists you have chosen to generate.